# cordova/phonegap 1.6 crash at second launch

Tags: iphone, cordova, crash, xcode4.3

**i use xcode 4.3.2 with phonegap 1.6. my app runs well the first time, but if i close the app in the ios simulator and i launch it for the second time, it crashes. Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably only in the simulator. I have had it a couple of times in the simulator but it never happened to me on-device.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having this issue, except in Android. This is with the release flag. More info can be found here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/v2-android-second-app-start-doesnt-work-for-release-version/125583

but here is a copy pasta in case the link goes down:

> #### Synopsis:
>
> My app has a canvas on it on the page html. On second start of initial install, app start doesn’t show canvas. I know because the body tag has a background and the canvas has a different background. The page does not have a module defined for it. ***This is only when built with --release***
>
> #### Environment:
>
> - Ionic: 3.20
> - Cordova: 7.1.0
> - Angular: 5.2.9
> - Android: 6.1.2 (I think build target 25)
> - jdk: 1.8
>
> #### Additional Info:
>
> I am sort of doing bleeding edge stuff, but I am now out of the realm of being able to solve this on my own. I am using pixi.js, specifically from an additional interface library called angular2pixi. A2p doesn’t support --aot building.
>
> Before I go on, let me reiterate *everything works, even on multiple app restarts for everything other than --release*.
>
> The top level architecture is fairly simple:
> a2p provides a service that has an instance of pixi. My app uses that service and has a page with a canvas awaiting Pixi’s rendering. When the app initializes, it starts up the pixi service, passing it the canvas reference and voila: html5ified angular.
>
> I have offloaded the actual initialization of the rendering to a user clicked button to make sure it’s not something to do with life cycles but that didn’t work either. Even more interestingly, the button I made didn’t show when the app didn’t load. So likely, this means the ion-content itself isn’t showing!
>
> Most interestingly, **if I go into app info and delete storage (not cache) then it works on next app start!** I am using localstorage but I attempted removing all mentions of it and no luck. ***ALSO*** On second install, or rather what would more technically be an update, the app works on every start after that.
>
> This happens on android and I can’t seem to replicate it in iOS other than the first time I tried. Because it is a release build, it’s difficult to debug. I attempted using Ionic Pro Monitoring to no avail.
>
> So far, my leanings are:
>
> - some type of caching causing a bug with the canvas itself
> - an error that is causing cordova or ionic to terminate
> - problem with my build process
> - a2p’s architecture (how could I go about debugging this given I have little knowledge of the underlying mechanics of cordova/ng2 -> native compilation?)
> - a cordova plugin (perhaps causing one of the above)
>
> So as you can probably tell from my formatting, I’m somewhere between nerd heaven and hell. Such a fascinating problem… but plis halp